# .net International Address Manager Library

Tags: library, .net, localization

I'm looking for a library which could manages all kind of addresses all around the world, and giving a useful data(base) representation (it's important to have a decent data structure), also to have the ability to get metadata and build UI for getting addresses based on that metadata. Address parsing is not the main goal here, but it would be nice.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found anything particular for this, however I realized data structure of Google Geocoding API is capable for handling any address over the world. You can build logic using Google's data structure and other services.

More info: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Types